# Pigeonhole principle and sums

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Given 69 integers not exceeding 100, prove that you can find a,b,c,d such that a+b+c=d. Is this true for 68 numbers?

Comment: I have solved your problem. If you want to see the solution show your work and everything you have tried to solve this problem so far.

Comment: I suspect there is an extra condition on the integers that has not been specified e.g. the integers have to be distinct positive integers. Other $\{1,1,1\dots 1 \}$ appears to contradict the assertion.

Comment: It is easy to find 68 integers $\le100$ such that no three sum to a fourth. Can you at least do that part of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $~a,~b,~c,~d~$ be such that $~a\lt b<c~$ and $~a+b+c=d~$.

Also let the numbers be $~1 ≤ a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_{69} ≤ 100~$.

Clearly $~a_1 ≤ 32~$.

Consider the sequence
$$a_3 + a_1 < a_4 + a_1 < \cdots < a_{69} + a_1$$
$$a_3 − a_2 < a_4 − a_2 < \cdots < a_{69} − a_2~.$$
Each of their terms is a positive integer not exceeding $~100 + 32 = 132~$. Since the two
sequences have jointly $~67+67 = 134~$ terms, there must exist indices $~i, j \in \{3, 4, \cdots , 69\}~$
such that $~a_i + a_1 = a_j − a_2~$. We have $~a_1 < a_2 < a_i~$
, and since $~a_1 + a_2 + a_i = a_j~$
, the
first part is done.

A counterexample for the second part is given by the set $~\{33, 34, 35, \cdots , 100\}~$.

Ref.: https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/amy-online/amy_sample_wm.pdf